# Insertion sort of strings that exist in an array

Tags: c, insertion-sort

In this program, I get an integer number from the user, for example 3, and the user enters 3 strings. Then I should find the longest string, and print it in reverse.

But I think that my insertion sort code has a problem, and I can't find it.

This is the complete code :

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

static void fatal(const char *msg)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", msg);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

int main(void)
{
    int n;

    printf("How many strings do you want to enter? ");
    if (1 != scanf("%d", &n) || 1 > n || n > 32)
        fatal("Invalid size specified.");

    char strings[n][64];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("Please enter string #%d: ", i + 1);
        if (1 != scanf("%63s", strings[i]))
            fatal("Invalid string input.");
    }
    char selected[100];
    int o;
    int j;
    for (j = 1; j < n; j++)
    {
        strcpy(selected, strings[j]);
        o = j - 1;
        while ((j >= 0) && (strcmp(selected, strings[o]) > 0))
        {
            strcpy(strings[o+1], strings[o]);
            o--;
        }
        strcpy(strings[o + 1], selected);
    }
    puts(strrev(strings[n-1]));
}
```

Insertion sort part:

```c
char selected[100];
int o;
int j;
for (j = 1; j < n; j++)
{
    strcpy(selected, strings[j]);
    o = j - 1;
    while ((j >= 0) && (strcmp(selected, strings[o]) > 0))
    {
        strcpy(strings[o+1], strings[o]);
        o--;
    }
    strcpy(strings[o + 1], selected);
}
```

Comment: If all that's desired is the longest string, then why do a sort of the entire string array?  Just keep track of the longest string on the fly.  It doesn't even need to store more than two strings at once:  The longest string so far, and the new string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we modify your code *slightly* to simply print the `strings` array after sorting, we can see that not all has gone according to plan.

```
$ ./a.out
How many strings do you want to enter? 3
Please enter string #1: hello
Please enter string #2: foo
Please enter string #3: wooble
0:
1: hello
2: foo
```

With some slight modifications, we can properly implement [selection sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort) and get the right order.

We must iterate `n-1` times over the array. On each iteration we'll move the shortest element forward, meaning we can consider this sorted. On each iteration an iteration of the remaining array must be performed to find the index of the shortest element.

We can then use a series of calls to `strcpy` (using `char temp[100]` as a temp buffer) to swap the strings.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

static void fatal(const char *msg)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", msg);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

int main(void)
{
    int n;

    printf("How many strings do you want to enter? ");
    if (1 != scanf("%d", &n) || 1 > n || n > 32)
        fatal("Invalid size specified.");

    char strings[n][64];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("Please enter string #%d: ", i + 1);
        if (1 != scanf("%63s", strings[i]))
            fatal("Invalid string input.");
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
    {
        int shortest_length = strlen(strings[i]);
        int shortest_len_idx = i;

        for (int j = i+1; j < n; j++) {
            if (strlen(strings[j]) < shortest_length) {
                shortest_len_idx = j;
            }
        }

        char temp[100] = {0};

        strcpy(temp, strings[i]);
        strcpy(strings[i], strings[shortest_len_idx]);
        strcpy(strings[shortest_len_idx], temp);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) printf("%d: %s\n", i, strings[i]);
}
```

```
$ ./a.out
How many strings do you want to enter? 3
Please enter string #1: hello
Please enter string #2: foo
Please enter string #3: wooble
0: foo
1: hello
2: wooble
```

You might also use a struct to "cache" each strings length, preventing repeated calls to `strlen`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_STR_LEN 64

typedef struct {
    int length;
    char str[MAX_STR_LEN];
} string_info;

static void fatal(const char *msg)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", msg);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

int main(void)
{
    int n;

    printf("How many strings do you want to enter? ");
    if (1 != scanf("%d", &n) || 1 > n || n > 32)
        fatal("Invalid size specified.");

    string_info strings[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("Please enter string #%d: ", i + 1);
        char fmt[100] = {0};
        sprintf(fmt, "%%%ds", MAX_STR_LEN-1);
        if (1 != scanf(fmt,  strings[i].str))
            fatal("Invalid string input.");
        strings[i].length = strlen(strings[i].str);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
    {
        int shortest_length = strings[i].length;
        int shortest_len_idx = i;
        for (int j = i+1; j < n; j++) {
            if (strings[j].length < shortest_length) {
                shortest_len_idx = j;
            }
        }

        string_info temp;

        strcpy(temp.str, strings[i].str);
        strcpy(strings[i].str, strings[shortest_len_idx].str);
        strcpy(strings[shortest_len_idx].str, temp.str);

        temp.length = strings[i].length;
        strings[i].length = strings[shortest_len_idx].length;
        strings[shortest_len_idx].length = temp.length;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) printf("%d: %s\n", i, strings[i].str);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.
your answer was complete and useful.

Comment: If all that's desired is the longest string, then why do a sort of the entire string array?  Just keep track of the longest string on the fly.  It doesn't even need to store more than two strings at once:  The longest string so far, and the new string.

Comment: @Fe2O3 Thank you for pointing that out. It has been rectified.

Comment: I went based on the code in the question which also would not read strings with whitespace.

Comment: The code in the question tries to output the longest string... reversed... Jus' sayin'